# jQuery .not() function not working within .parent() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to links within paragraphs whose paragraphs don't have immediate text, but the class is being added to every link.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
$('.card p a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().not($(this)).text()) {
    $(this).addClass('noTextDecoration');
  }
});
```

```css
.noTextDecoration {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id <a href="#">dui posuere blandit</a>. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
  <p><a href="#">learn more</a></p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id <a href="#">dui posuere blandit</a>. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The parent is never equal to the element itself, so the `.not()` condition will always be true.

Comment: So does that mean I can't use `.not()` in this case?

Comment: No, it doesn't do what you want to do. `$(selector).not($(this))` means return all the elements that match `selector` except the ones that are equal to `this`.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to see if the paragraph element has text except for the text in the child elements, so i'm looking at the parent element of the child, excluding itself (child).

Comment: When you use `.parent()`, you get the `p` element. `.not()` then removes the current `a` element from that collection. But the `a` isn't in the collection, so there's nothing to remove. A collection doesn't include the children.

Comment: And `.text()` always includes the text in nested elements. See the linked question for the way to do what you want.

Comment: But it would be easier if you put the outer text in their own `<span>`, then you could select that.